# How to get query result in Json form using Java API of Google Bigquery

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am using Google Bigquery V2 Java API. I am not able to find a way to get query results in JSON format. 
In Bigquery Web UI we can see this JSON and Table form of results. see scrrenshot.

Is there any way to get the **GetQueryResultsResponse** as JSON, using Java API. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to apply the [`TO_JSON_STRING` function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#to_json_string) to the results of your query. For example,

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t)
FROM (
  SELECT x, y
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE z = 10
) AS t;
```

If you want all of the table's columns as JSON, you can use a simpler form:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t)
FROM YourTable AS t
WHERE z = 10;
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem. Can we get query result in JSON format using JAVA API ??

Comment: How does Google show JSON results on Web UI. Does it explicitly converts result response to JSON form ?

Comment: Can you describe why this doesn't solve your problem? The client libraries take the JSON responses from the BigQuery service and convert them into native representations for each language (Java, Python, etc.). If you want the results as JSON strings, you can use this function.

Comment: I am working at API level. For me I can not change user's query or don't want to force the user to use TO_JSON_STRING function.
Is there any way to convert native representation of response to JSON string. similar to Bigquery Web UI.

Comment: I have the same question. I also want to avoid using TO_JSON_STRING function, because not only I have to modify the original SQL but also the json output format of this function is different than the json output format of exporting the table. The command `bq query --format json --project_id myProject "select * from sandbox.keweiquerytable"` can query a table and result in json format. So I suppose there should be a way to do that in REST or JAVA API. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Please post a separate question instead of asking in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a service account to access the BigQuery REST API to get the response in JSON format.

In order to use a service account, you will have to go to credentials (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) and choose a project.

[image: Click on the credentials button]

You will get a drop down like this:
[image: Select Service Account from the options]

Create a Service account for your project and download the secret file in the JSON format. Keep the JSON file in your file system and set the path to it. Check below image to set the file path:

[image: Set the key as shown the image and path to the credentials image]

So, now all you have to do in is use JAVA client api to consume the Big Query REST API.

Here's is a simple solution that I've been using for my project.

```
package com.example.bigquery;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpContent;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.common.io.CharStreams;

public class BigQueryDemo {

    private static final String QUERY_URL_FORMAT = "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/%s/queries" + "?access_token=%s";

    private static final String QUERY = "query";

    private static final String QUERY_HACKER_NEWS_COMMENTS = "SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:hacker_news.comments] LIMIT 1000";

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BigQueryDemo.class);

    static GoogleCredential credential = null;
    static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
    static {
        // Authenticate requests using Google Application Default credentials.
        try {
            credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
            credential = credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery"));
            credential.refreshToken();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void implicit() {
        String projectId = credential.getServiceAccountProjectId();
        String accessToken = generateAccessToken();
        // Set the content of the request.
        Dataset dataset = new Dataset().addLabel(QUERY, QUERY_HACKER_NEWS_COMMENTS);
        HttpContent content = new JsonHttpContent(JSON_FACTORY, dataset.getLabels());
        // Send the request to the BigQuery API.
        GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(String.format(QUERY_URL_FORMAT, projectId, accessToken));
        logger.debug("URL: " + url.toString());
        String responseJson = getQueryResult(content, url);
        logger.debug(responseJson);
    }

    private static String getQueryResult(HttpContent content, GenericUrl url) {
        String responseContent = null;
        HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = HTTP_TRANSPORT.createRequestFactory();
        HttpRequest request = null;
        try {
            request = requestFactory.buildPostRequest(url, content);
            request.setParser(JSON_FACTORY.createJsonObjectParser());
            request.setHeaders(
                    new HttpHeaders().set("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "POST").setContentType("application/json"));
            HttpResponse response = request.execute();
            InputStream is = response.getContent();
            responseContent = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(is));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
        return responseContent;
    }

    private static String generateAccessToken() {
        String accessToken = null;
        if ((System.currentTimeMillis() > credential.getExpirationTimeMilliseconds())) {
            accessToken = credential.getRefreshToken();
        } else {
            accessToken = credential.getAccessToken();
        }
        System.out.println(accessToken);
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

Following is the Github link to the code: https://github.com/vslala/BigQueryRestSample

It is just a demo project to fetch JSON data from the BQ REST API. Do not use it in your project directly. 
Let me know if you have any questions.